# Why my app crahes when pass CVImageBufferRef variable to other class

Tags: ios

My project was written in Swift, and I tried to rewrite it in Objective-C.App goes well in Swift, but in Objective-C it crashes.Since the project is complicated, I wrote a demo App based on Apple's sample code "SquareCam" to make it simple. You can get the code from Github:https://github.com/jaypeggy/SquareCam.

Run the app using Xcode(7.2) with your iphone, switch the camera to front by tapping the segment control in toolbar, After a few seconds,the app will crash here:

```
    - (void)run {
    while (1) {
        CVImageBufferRef a = [self getImageBuffer];
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(a, 0);
        sleep(1);
        NSLog(@"111111");
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(a, 0);// crash here
    }
}
```

the app work like this:

(1)"SquareCamViewController.m" get a CVPixelBufferRef variable using CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer.

```
`- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{   
    NSLog(@"captureOutput");
    // got an image
    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);`
```

(2) a instance of class test(sorry for bad name) set "pixelBuffer" to its own variable.

CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
[t setImageBuffer:pixelBuffer]; //set "pixelBuffer" to itself.

(3)At the same time, class test(test.m) is running in another thread(queue), and trying to get the "CVImageBufferRef" varibale, and call CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress and CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress to do further process.

```
    - (void)run {
    while (1) {
        CVImageBufferRef a = [self getImageBuffer];
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(a, 0);
        sleep(1);
        NSLog(@"111111");
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(a, 0); // crash here
    }
}
```

In my original project, it crashes even sooner:

```
    void CVImageBufferRef_to_cvGRAY(CVImageBufferRef imgBuf, cv::Mat &imgOut)
{
// lock the buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imgBuf, 0); // maybe crash here

    // get the address to the image data
    void *imgBufAddr = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imgBuf, 0);

    // get image properties
    int w = (int)CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imgBuf);
    int h = (int)CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imgBuf);

    cv::Mat mColor(h, w, CV_8UC4, (void*)imgBufAddr);
    cv::cvtColor(mColor, (imgOut), COLOR_BGRA2GRAY); // maybe crash here
    // unlock again
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imgBuf, 0);
    mColor.~Mat();

}
```

it have taken me a few days to deal with this problem, but I have no idea how to solve this, is it about mutithread? Why Swift code run and Objective-C crash ?

---

can anybody help me? thanks a lot.

Comment: probably you run several instances of this func in time, or camera capture is overwriting buffer, add some checks to avoid multiple run and overwrite